# How to make autocomplete on HMVC codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I had HMVC codeigniter project, and I want to create auto complete on fields, but no matter I tried it just won't work, I'm using CI 3, php 5.5 +

This is my controller (test):

```
function getData() {

    $name = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $query = $this->ex_model->getThisData()->like('name', $name)->get();

    foreach ($query->result() as $q) {
        $res['query'] = $name;
        $res['suggestions'][] = array(
            'value'=>$q->name,
            'gender'=>$q->gender,
            'id'=>$q->id,
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($res);
}
```

Thus, my model (ex_model):

```
function getThisData(){
    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->from('table1');
    $this->db->join('table2', 'table1.id= table2.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Lastly, my view + JavaScript:

```
<input  type="search" id="data1" placeholder="Input Name..." class="form-control border-input">

var site = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
$(function(){

    $('#data1').autocomplete({
        serviceURL: site+'/test/getData',

        onSelect:function(suggestion){
            $('#id').val(''+suggestion.id);
            $('#gender').val(''+suggestion.gender);
        }
    });
});
```

And my URL that moment:

```
http://localhost/myproject/admin/test
```

I don't know how URI segment on HMVC ci works, I tried with segment(4) and (5) still dont show the auto complete.

There's no errors, but the data on input field won't show, I want to know if I should fix "$this->uri->segment(3)" or my javascripts or else.

Comment: What's not working what r u getting?

Comment: @devpro, there's no errors, but the data on input field won't show, i want to know if i should fix "$this->uri->segment(3)" or my javascripts or else

Comment: Chk the answer this will help u

Answer (score 0):

As per your URL:

```
http://localhost/myproject/admin/test/getData
```

You can't get the values as segment (4) and (5).

You need to use like this:

```
$this->uri->segment(1); // admin
$this->uri->segment(2); // test
$this->uri->segment(3); // getData
```

*You can also follow the user manual: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html*

According to manual and your URL:

You segment should be:

```
1- admin 
2- test 
3- getData
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but what should i do with my javascript? should i fix the 'base_url' or 'serviceURL'? the data still wont show btw

Comment: @teletubbies use segment as u r using this var site = "<?php echo base_url();?>";

Comment: still wont show the data list on input field, i follow some tutorial that didnt use Wiredezignz HMVC extensions though

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter the segment is started after the name of the main domain:

For example :**http://localhost/myproject/admin/test/getData**  here **http://localhost/myproject** is the main domain so the segment will start from **admin**.
here **admin** is number 1 segment **test** is second and *getData* is third.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the main problem is autocomplete wont show the data on input field

Comment: what is the output of <?php echo base_url();?>. I mean, is admin included in the base_url() ?

Comment: localhost/myproject, i use wiredezignz HMVC extensions btw

Comment: change this serviceURL: site+'/test/getData' into this  serviceURL: site+'/admin/test/getData'

Answer (score 0):

Without checking JS code, your controller and model don't fit:

1. Your model is already returning array (or FALSE) so there is no need for

   ```
   $query = $this->ex_model->getThisData()->like('name', $name)->get();
   ```

It should be:

```
$query = $this->ex_model->getThisData();
```

2. You are trying to filter query by parameter so you need to pass that to model:

   ```
   $name = $this->uri->segment(4) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : null;

   $query = $this->ex_model->getThisData($name);
   ```
3. Now your model's method code should looks like:

   ```
   public function getThisData($name)
   {
       if ($name != null) {
           $this->db->select('name');//should this be '*'?
           $this->db->from('table1');
           $this->db->where('name', $name)
           $this->db->join('table2', 'table1.id= table2.id');
           $query = $this->db->get();
           return $query->result_array();//remember if you return array or object and you are probably looking for result, but not for single row here?
       }
       //case when $name value from controller is null
       return false;
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i tried but autocomplete still wont work, i just made some changes on my project so my url like:http://localhost/myproject/admin/test
should i change the uri segment to 3?